# Url.Action Not figuring out the actual url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use Url.Action to generate the correct HTTP URL based on a controller action like this : 
`$.post('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Delete", new { id = "1" }))')`

However, it is not working as expected . The actual url fired (got this from dev tools) is 
`http://localhost:60223/CordBlood/@Html.Raw(Url.Action(%22Delete%22,%20new%20%7B%20id%20=%20%224%22%20%7D))`

Whereas I want something like this : 
`http://localhost:60223/CordBlood/Delete/1`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this code in a .js file?  Or in your .cshtml file?  Also, your stack trace has nothing to do with this problem, that's just the result of requesting the bad url.

Comment: Hmm -- you shouldn't need to use `Html.Raw`? Other than that, the code should work fine... can you please post a slightly larger example?

Comment: In the code sample you provided, the ending single quote is in the wrong place. You have two parentheses at the beginning, but three at the end.

Comment: @MystereMan This is in a cshtml file.

Comment: @Pandincus there is a problem in the single quote but that is just a mistake I did while pasting code here. It is good in the code i am using

Comment: Is there anything you aren't telling us about this code?  Is it in a partial view?  Is it part of method you are calling?  You really shouldn't use the Raw.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achieve  something similar to this

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dropdown").change(function () {
                var id = $("#dropdown").val();

                if (id == "")
                { id = 0; }
                var dataToSend = {
                    Id: id

                };
                RedirectToPage(id);
            });
            function RedirectToPage(id) {
                var url = '@Url.Action("Delete", "yourController", new { Id = "__id__" })';

                window.location.href = url.replace('__id__', id);
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Hope this will give you some idea

Comment: I am trying to do something similar. Except tht you are doing a window.location and I am doing a ajax.post

I am also trying to do url.replace but the only difference is that I am trying to do a `url.replace(/__ID__/, id)`